Showing linear independence of 2 vectors
Let $A$ be some square matrix bigger than $4 \times 4$ such that $A$ is nilpotent. Let $x,y$ be 2 linearly independent vectors such $A^2x=A^2y=0$ but $Ax\neq 0,Ay\neq 0$. I wish to show that $(x,y,Ax,Ay)$ are linearly independent.
Therefore, let $a,b,c,d$ be scalars such that $ax+by+cAx+dAy=0.$ Applying $A$ on both sides yields $aAx+bAy=A(ax+by)=0.$ How can we proceed? The next step would be to show that $ax+by=0$, but I can't figure out how. Can we somehow use the property that $x,y\in \ker(A^2)\setminus\ker(A),$ but $ax+by\in \ker(A)?$
Edited to give the question more sense. The underlying idea is to prove that 2 Jordan chains are linearly independent, i.e. a matrix with with 2 chains each of size 2 should exist, and the basis vectors should be of the form $(x,y,Ax,Ay)$ as above. Perhaps I am understanding something wrong, much thanks to all the corrections.
Another edit: I am talking about the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

@kem711 If $A^2=0$, why do you feel the need to say that $A^2 x = A^2 y =0$?

You are right sorry for the stupid mistake. I think that property is not necessary, and will remove it.

Surely incorrect - take $A(a,b)^t = (b,0)^t$ - so $A$ is a 2X2 matrix. Set $x=(1,1)^t$, and $y=(0,1)^t$. Then $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, $A^2=0$, and neither $Ax$ nor $Ay$ is zero, but of course no four vectors are lin. ind. in a 2-dim v.s.

@peterag You should post an answer, but maybe assume that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $n \ge 4$, even if it's not stated in the OP, and construct a counter-example.

@peterag Maybe we are assuming dim $\ge 4$?

Counter-example would still work in higher dimensions - add some zeros?

@PierreCarre maybe, but it's possible that the OP has the wrong question, so my counter-example might reasonably count as a 'comment'

I have added some more clarification.

@kern711 as I wrote above, the same counter-example, suitably modified, works in any dim greater than 1.

I see that my question has failed. I will try to ask a better question later.

What  about trying, "there exists $x$ and $y$ such that...

Following @peterag 's comment, it is very easy to produce counter-examples. Consider, for instance, $x=(0,1,0,1)$, $ y=(0,1,1,0)$ and $$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Considering that $A y = A x \ne 0 $, we must conclude that the proposed result does not hold.

One can even use the OP's choice of $A$, with $x=(1,1,0,0)^t$, and $y=(0,1,0,0)^t$.

btw, the "@" does not work in answers - I didn't get the 'red' notification. I'm not sure, but I don't think it even works in a comment to an answer, unless it's a response to another comment to the SAME answer (i.e, if I had commented only on the original question, and someone tries to @ me in the comments on the answer, I won't see it). Also, I think the op does not get notified to comments on an answer - of course the answerer does
